# QGIS Join table with shp file. Get Null Values on the join fields

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

If my problem is that my ID types are not the same, I need help in addressing that.  I started with an excel file, I read that on a mac to I need to save that as a Windows comma Separated file.  I did.

QGIS 2.14
Add Layer - Add Delimited Text Layer - 
[image: Adding Layer]

[image: Joining]

**the csv file has**

- parcel_num as text
- situs_cmptaddr_number as text
- acres as double

**After join the Shp file has**

- PARCEL_NUM as string
- situs_cmptaddr_number as text
- acres as double

I have tried loading the csv file as a vector layer with a like named .csvt file but it did not pick the the details in the csvt file.

I am new to QGIS.

My file names are --- mailingList_w_csv.csv and mailingList_w_csv.csvt.

I am using a mac.  I have since used a PC to create the csv file from an excel file.  the csvt file is being edited on my mac

The csvt file looks like this - “String”,”Text”,”Double”

Comment: Add Delimited Text Layer does not evaluate csvt files. (csvt files are only used by Add Vector Layer.) Is there a screenshot #3 missing in the question? Can you share test data?

Comment: Afaik, "Text" is not a valid option in csvt according to http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html. The whole csvt will be ignored if there is an error in it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer !! Download Open Office.  Open the CSV file as a text document in Open Office.  Then save as a dbf file.  Then add new Vector Layer with the dbf file. Worked beautifully.  I lost the link to the helpful article.  There was just one sentence on this topic, which is summarized above.